# Why does IE prompts for installing ActiveX control in a .cab but then blocks it anyway?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I am embedding an ActiveX control (not developed by me) into a website, deployed in a .cab file.

At first the control was not loaded but, after adding my webserver to the Trusted site list, I can get IE to prompt me whether I want to install the .cab or not

[image: Cab installation prompt]

I click 'yes' but then I cannot access the controls of the .ocx, and I keep on getting "Object doesn't support property or method..." errors.
If I manually register the .ocx and the .ax files in the cab, everything works fine.

Is there a way to understand why IE is blocking the control although I'm telling it to run it?

Answer (score 0):

If the ActiveX control is not being installed from a code signed cab file then IE cannot verify its authenticity and as such will actively block it.

Steps to fix this:

1) Add the website to the trusted sites in Internet Explorer Options -> Security and set the security level to **low** or to a custom level allowing unsafe or unsigned ActiveX control to run.

2) Ask the publisher of the third party control for a code signed  cab file. many publisher do provide this option on request after purchase of a license. please confirm this with them.